# Moving Telerik controls between machines

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I'm moving telerik enabled website between servers. I'm not original developer, I'm just sysadmin moving websites. After the move JavaScript throws error:

> "Telerik is not defined" on line Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox,
>   {"_dropDownWidth":0

Is there a specific thing I need to be concerned about moving between systems. Like if Telerik was not initialized due to missing may be license key or I'm not sure how properly move this setup around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the DevToolbar in Chrome (F12) and inspect the JS requests - some of them have probably got either 404 or 503 HTTP code.

Depending on that you can check [this help topic](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#error-message-telerik-is-undefined-when-running-a-website-on-iis-7-integrated-mode) and find a solution